# What's the best way to add an additional property for each property in an object in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

First off I want to say I know there are easy ways around this issue but just by googleing and looking on stackoverflow it doesn't seem like there is a set way you are suppose to go about doing this so I wanted to see if anyone out there had ran into this before and came out with a nice solution.  Here is my issue, I want to add an additional property for each property in an object.  This works fine in newer IEs and in Firefox but will cause an infinite loop in IE8.

```
var oObject = { One : '1', Two : '2' };

for ( var key in oObject ) // Loops twice in IE10 and FF, loops infinitely in IE8
{
  console.log(oObject[key]);
  oObject[key+'_additionalProperty'] = 'Test';
}
```

Is there a way to do this without having to create a variable that holds the original value of oObject just to add an additional property for each property in oObject?

Note: For those jQuery fans out there $.each has the same issue. Also, I wish I could just not support IE8.

**UPDATE:**

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/dwaddell/rH89K/

Additional information: I actually haven't tested this in a true IE browser, I have been using the Developer Tools from IE10 and selecting IE8 for Browser Mode and IE 8 standards for Document Mode.  This may make some kind of difference, I am not sure.

Comment: The code you provided works fine for me in IE8, maybe there is something else that causes this problem?

Comment: @Fibbe I'll make a jsFiddle when I get a minute, I watered down the code to what I thought was the issue.  There is a little more I am doing so maybe something is adding to the problem.

Comment: @Fibbe When switching to IE8 within IE10 I get a console.log of Test a bunch of times until I get a "SCRIPT7: Out of memory " error. I think I have a computer with just IE8 on it around here, I'll have to try it out to see if I get the same problem.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't add keys in the for loop. You're probably just infinitely adding keys with more and more `_additionalProperty` suffixes. Try outputting just the `key` value in the for loop.

Comment: Yep that is exactly what is going on, just for IE8 though. @Fibbe's answer describes what is likely the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, IE8 doesn't cache the properties list when using `for...in`. So, you continually add keys... adding additional properties for your additional properties and so on.

At any rate, a safeguard is to get your keys first like so ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/HsfnC/)):

```js
var oObject = {
  One: '1',
  Two: '2'
};

var keys = []; // plain array for caching our keys

// add keys to our cache
for (var key in oObject) {
  keys.push(key);
}

// loop through the cached keys and add new properties to oObject
for (var i = 0, ln = keys.length; i < ln; i++) {
  oObject[keys[i] + "_additionalProperty"] = "test";
}

console.log(oObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var oObject = { One : '1', Two : '2' };
var keys = Object.keys(oObject);
for ( var i=0;i<keys.length;i++) // Loops twice in IE10 and FF, loops infinitely in IE8
{
  oObeject[keys[i]+'_additionalProperty'] = 'Test';
}
```

Edit:

Your code should work as it is:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg622937(v=vs.85).aspx

Edit 2:

An implementation of Object.Keys for ie8

```
Object.keys = Object.keys || function(o) {  
    var result = [];  
    for(var name in o) {  
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(name))  
          result.push(name);  
    }  
    return result;  
};
```

http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/10/a-safer-object-keys-compatibility-implementation

Comment: Thanks @Pheonix, I did think of using that but alas Object.keys does not exist in IE8.  I may add a compatibility function to include it, it is just bugging me that there isn't an easy way to go about doing this in IE8.

Comment: @dwaddell added an Edit, Btw could you do a document.write or alert inside the loop in ie8 and see what it is looping over ? sorry no access to ie8 here.